# Can't convert [Double] to Double within function

Tags: arrays, swift, function, types, type-conversion

How do I make this run without getting this error?

> Cannot invoke 'stride' with an argument list of type '(from: Double, to: [Double], by: Double)'

I know the answer is right there but I'm new to coding and am having trouble making that [double] just a double within the func.

```
var array = [50.0, 40.0, 60.0]
var newArray = [Float]()

func possible(variable: [Double]) -> Float {
    var chance: Double = 0.0
    let last = variable
    let interval = -10.0
    for _ in stride(from: 100.0, to: last, by: interval) {
        chance += 0.05
    }
    return Float(chance)
}

newArray.append(possible(variable: array))
```

I get why it doesn't work, because I'm telling last to be an array. But how do I make it run each component of array individually. I thought doing `let last = (variable[index])` would work but it did not.

Ideally the end result would be `newArray = [0.25, 0.3, 0.2]`

Comment: Is it supposed to be a `[Double]` in the first place? `last` doesn't sound like something that should be a list. I think you need to elaborate on your intent here.

Comment: `variable` is an array of `Double`. But the `to` parameter of `stride` needs a specific `Double`. `last` is set to the array, not a specific number.

Comment: @Carcigenicate   What I want is for all 3 components of array to go through the function and passed out into a new array of 3 floats. So Ideally the end result would be newArray = [0.25, 0.3, 0.2]

Comment: @rmaddy I tried doing let last = (variable[index]) thinking that would work but it didn't.

Answer (score 2):

You need your `variable` parameter to be a single `Double`, not an array. Then you need to call `possible` once for each value in `array`.

Here's one way to update your code:

```
var array = [50.0, 40.0, 60.0]

func possible(variable: Double) -> Float {
    var chance: Double = 0.0
    let interval = -10.0
    for _ in stride(from: 100.0, to: variable, by: interval) {
        chance += 0.05
    }
    return Float(chance)
}

let newArray = array.map { possible(variable: $0) }
print(newArray)
```

But here's an simpler implementation of `possible`:

```
func possible(variable: Double) -> Float {
    return Float((100 - variable) / 10 * 0.05)
}
```

Your entire set of code can be reduced to:

```
var array = [50.0, 40.0, 60.0]
let newArray = array.map { Float((100 - $0) / 10 * 0.05) }
```

Comment: purrrrrfect! Thanks rmaddy, your the bomb.com and thanks Carcigenicate for contributing

Comment: @rmaddy How come only the first element in the  newArray is a float and the rest are doubles?

Comment: They are all Float. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: because when I run it, the result is [0.25, 0.200000003, 0.200000003, 0.300000012, 0.349999994, 0.264999986, 0.264999986]

Comment: Welcome to floating point math where not all numbers can be represented exactly. You will get slightly better results using `Double` instead of `Float`.